# Developing js while using elixir

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-elixir

I am developing the js of a laravel-5, AngularJS app right now.  I am using elixir to version the css and js files.  However while I am developing I don't want to have to have to version my files everytime I want to test something.

What is the best way to use elixir while you are still in active development?

I know you can use gulp watch but won't that create a new compiled version of the code everytime I save?  Those files could add up fast.

Related Question: Should I commit the built files to version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having developed with gulp for a few weeks now, `gulp watch` is really good at quickly recognizing the change and firing a rebuild on the file.  Plus, it does delete the previous file.

So, Elixir keeps only 1 compiled version of each file. And it builds them quickly so `gulp watch` is a good solution.

Personally I think it is a very bad idea to version these files.  For one they are always being deleted and recompiled.  Lastly it is generated code that can (and should) be generated in production.